How to show database information in html page using javascript
In freecodecamp's javascript oop course, step 13, object´s values inside an array are shown in boxes, the array being just a big list declared in the script.js. I wanted to do the same but with data from a database i have, i managed to connect the database to my script.js using node.js and put the table's info in a list of objects, but i could not find a way to link an html element into the script so that the information could be added to it, because node.js apparently wont allow it. Is there a way to do this withouth running a live server, so just openning the index.html from my files?
I tried looking for a way to do this and i found ways of doing it with python, django, flask, and other js libraries like express.js, but they all required a live server running with https.
This is what i tried in the script.js
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "gatobase"
});

con.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
    con.query("select Color,edad,raza,peso from 
    gatos_sin_adoptar",function (err,result,fields){
    if (err) throw err;
    gatos = result;
})

gatos.forEach(
    ({ color, edad, raza, peso }) => {

        gatoCajas.innerHTML += `
    <div class="gato_caja">
      <p class="gatoColor">Color: ${color}</p>
      <p class="gatoEdad">Edad: ${edad}</p>
      <p class="gatoRaza">Raza: ${raza}</p>
      <p class="gatoPeso">Peso: ${peso} Kg</p>
    </div>
    `;
    }
);

But it always throws this error which i found out its due to node.js
    c:\Users\Nicolás\Desktop\Gatoprojecto\script.js:2 const    gatoCajas=document.getElementById("gatoContainer") ^

    ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> 
    (c:\Users\Nicolás\Desktop\Gatoprojecto\script.js:2:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] 
    (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
    Node.js v18.13.0


Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I believe you are perhaps confused about the difference between client-side javascript (in the browser, where document exists) and server-side javascript (node.js stuff, where database connections exist, but not HTML documents)?

I am aware there are differences in their behaviour, i just want to know how to properly connect them so i can show the database information from the sever-side node.js in the client-side document.

I’m not familiar with node.js, but document.getElementById() needs to run inside the browser. I realize this is confusing because on the internet we often say “javascript” when we really mean “browser APIs”. I’m sorry you have to suffer this mess. There are of course also upsides to using Javascript on the server.

You gotta move the database data to the client first, for example by printing it into the HTTP response. Sorry, I don’t know node enough to give code examples.

Since you mentioned other server-side languages requiring a HTTP server… You need one for node.js as well. I see the course you’re doing is only about browser-side javascript. You won’t be able to access your database from there! Even if you’re only trying to make a local webapp running on your computer, there must be a program serving HTTP to the browser.
